# How can EC2 between different regions communicate through intranet on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

ap-east-1,us-west-2,eu-north-1 we have these different regions, and I want to communicate through intranet,may be need use VPC. Could you please tell me how to config vpc, route, and subnets?

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) between the two VPCs in different regions. With the peering,

> Traffic always stays on the global AWS backbone, and **never traverses the public internet**, which reduces threats, such as common exploits, and DDoS attacks.

How to set it up is explained in detail in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the information presented, the best option in your case as Marcin suggested is to use VPC Peering. You need to bear in mind that you can't peer VPCes with overlapping VPC CIDRs

Just for completion, there is another option to cross-connect VPCes from different accounts and regions called [Transit Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/how-transit-gateways-work.html). In your case, as you'll need to set up Transit Gateway Peering between the regions it may be a bit too complex.

Answer (score 0):

VPC Peering is a region specific service and so can join VPCs only within the same region.

If you want to establish communication without using public internet between VPCs across regions you may explore on "VPC Endpoint" and "VPC Endpoint Services" options. Please note some of these services are not free-tier eligible, in case you are experimenting.

Comment: VPC peering is not region specific. You can [peer VPCs across regions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/).